# How can I get un-drunk quickly?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

I got falling-down-drunk. Is there any way to sober up quickly? I didn't realise drinking so much would impair my ability to do things, I just wanted more adventures.

Comment: Mythbusters tested this. Exercising and getting slapped in the face seemed to be the most effective: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythBusters_(2008_season)#Stone_Cold_Sober

Comment: I don't know whether to trust your advice...

Comment: [Mike knows much, tells some. Mike knows many things that others do not.](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/M'aiq_the_Liar)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are a few ways to get sober other than simply waiting a day, none of them quick and none of them cheap. This is set as a built-in turn limitation, so you don't circumvent the 40 turns-per-day limit simply by guzzling booze and then taking sober pills.

There are, in effect, three ways of reducing drunkenness:

1. Spice melange - This is  a relatively rare drop from sandworms (usually found by using a drum machine). It reduces drunkenness and fullness by 3, but you can only use one a day.
2. Synthetic hair of the dog pill - This item is also hard to find as it requires the Transpondent effect, which is gained from an item dropped by an Item-of-the-Month familiar. You can buy the items in the Mall, but it's somewhat cost-ineffective to do so just to farm hair of the dog pills. This item reduces drunkenness by 1 and you can only use it once a day.
3. Ultra Mega Sour Ball - This item is a rare drop from the item 'huge bowl of candy'. It reduces drunkenness and fullness by 3, but you can only use one a day.
4. [The Towering Inferno Discotheque](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/The_Towering_Inferno_Discotheque) - You can choose one boon per day, and the fourth option decreases drunkenness by 1. You need to be wearing four pieces of equipment made of [unsmoothed velvet](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Unsmoothed_velvet) (the bra doesn't count). If you don't have a charter for the 70s volcano, you need to use a [one-day ticket](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/One-day_ticket_to_That_70s_Volcano) to get there. (If you want the the one-day ticket to be worth your investment, [do some mining](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Groovy_Geology:_Your_Guide_to_That_70s_Volcano#Unlocking_the_Velvet_.2F_Gold_Mine) or get powerful gear like [Mr. Cheeng's spectacles](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Mr._Cheeng's_spectacles) while you're there.)
5. [Calculate the Universe](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Calculate_the_Universe) - This is a complex skill that, once per day, does one of many things depending on a formula based on your stats. One of them (ending digits 11) is changing your drunkenness. Be careful, it might also make you *more* drunk; this is seemingly random. Getting this skill requires you to play some PvP during certain seasons.
6. Waiting for tomorrow - This is the "method" used by most players and probably the only one you currently have access. After rollover, your drunkenness is set to 0 again.

Answer (score 11):

The most common way of become un-drunk is to wait until rollover.  There are a few rare items (namely spice melange), that removes drunkenness per use, but they are very hard to obtain.

On a related note, if you obtain the Liver of Steel you can drink a little more before becoming totally inebriated.

As a strategy, most people drink up until their limit - which is 14 (19 with Liver of Steel) - and then, just before they log off for the day, drink a final big drink that pushes them over the top.

Comment: You've got the values switched there. It's 19 with liver of steel, 14 with liver.

Comment: @FAE oops, yep corrected